# java.lang.IllegalStateException: getResources().getString inside fragment - crash

Tags: java, android

While fetching data from back end using retrofit 2, if the error data is received the app crashed.

```
private String fetchErrorMessage(Throwable throwable) {
    String errorMsg = getResources().getString(R.string.error_msg_unknown);

    if (!isNetworkConnected()) {
        errorMsg = getResources().getString(R.string.error_msg_no_internet);
    } else if (throwable instanceof TimeoutException) {
        errorMsg = getResources().getString(R.string.error_msg_timeout);
    }

    return errorMsg;
}
```

> log cat showing this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireContext (Fragment.java:696)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getResources (Fragment.java:760)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getString (Fragment.java:782)
  at com.pixmama.contributor.fragment.HomeFragment$2.onFailure (HomeFragment.java:208)
```

Comment: is that happened in all android version or pie?

Comment: I am getting this rash mostly in Android 9 which is pie @RezaulKarim

Comment: In which method of the Fragment are you calling this code?

Comment: which is `HomeFragment.java:208` line of code?

Comment: A probable cause can be that `HomeFragment` no longer attached to Activity when this method is getting called ..

Comment: Check if the fragment is attached to the activity or not, by calling `isAdded()` method of fragment.

Comment: Okay I am checking this @GabrieleMariotti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use context to avoid. You can use `getActity()` as it is in fragment or use application context

```java
private String fetchErrorMessage(Throwable throwable) {

    String errorMsg = getResources().getString(R.string.error_msg_unknown);

    if (!isNetworkConnected()) {
        if (getActivity() != null){
        errorMsg = getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.error_msg_no_internet);
        }
    } else if (throwable instanceof TimeoutException) {
        if (getActivity() != null){
        errorMsg = getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.error_msg_timeout);
       }
    }

    return errorMsg;
}
```

Comment: avoid using getApplicationContext() as it may leak memory

Comment: thanks for your answer. It can be better answer @GabrieleMariotti

Answer (score 0):

Please try to get the fragment context like this:

```
getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.error_msg_unknown)
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If you are using a `android.app.Fragment`, the method `getResources()` uses `getActivity().getResources()`. If you are using support libraries or androidx libraries it uses `requireContext().getResources()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private String fetchErrorMessage(Throwable throwable) {
String errorMsg = getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.error_msg_unknown);

if (!isNetworkConnected()) {
    errorMsg = getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.error_msg_no_internet);
} else if (throwable instanceof TimeoutException) {
    errorMsg = getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.error_msg_timeout);
}

return errorMsg;}
```

Comment: Please add some description for this why it works and how

Comment: Check the `getResources()` method. You will discover that is `requireContext().getResources();`

Comment: @DineshKondapaneni To access the resource you need a context but you are inside of a fragment that is why you need to pass your parent activity context.

Comment: this does not make sense, as documentation says: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#getResources() It says that `Return getActivity().getResources()`

Answer (score 0):

Probably user already left the fragment by clicking back or navigated to other fragment and it is not attached to the activity therefore `requireContext` fails. You can check if fragment is attached by checking if `getActivity() == null`

Answer (score 0):

Check the doc.
The method `getResources()` uses `requireContext()` which return a NonNull object of the equivalent get methods or throw an `IllegalStateException`.

Check if the fragment is currently added to its activity using the [`isAdded()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#isAdded()) method.

Something like:

```
if (isAdded()){
   //your implementation....
   getResources().getString(R.string.error_msg_unknown);
}
```

Just a note: `isAdded()` and `getActivity()!=null` are not the same. You can check the implementation:

```
/**
 * Return true if the fragment is currently added to its activity.
 */
final public boolean isAdded() {
    return mHost != null && mAdded;
}
```